# How is the map labels language set in Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, localization, maps

In Google Maps Android API v1, I used to set up the default locale with `Locale.setDefault`. This localized the map's language. How this is done with the new apps?

Is it supported?

Comment: @thomaus I know this is old, but just as a heads up the map renders the language based on the devices set locale, thus the only way to change the language in google maps is to change the devices locale. At least htat is what I have found to this point.